# syntax tree about cleft sentences

Tags: syntax

I would like to know about the syntactic tree of cleft sentences. is the clefted elemnt moved from the original position? or Is it base-generated? 
I would like to knwo some referrences about this.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you referring to _It_-clefts or _Wh_-clefts? Or some other variety? There are many different kinds, all with puzzling restrictions.

Comment: i firstly think about it-clefts. but now I would like to know about the defferences between it-cleft and wh-cleft.

Comment: _The chicken ate the worm_ == _It_-Cleft ==> _It was the worm that the chicken ate_  and _It was the chicken that ate the worm_ (other constituents can be clefted besides subjects and objects).  _The timing belt destroyed the water pump_ == _Wh_-Cleft ==> _What the timing belt destroyed was the water pump_ and _What destroyed the water pump was the timing belt._ There are other varieties, but those are the most prominent.

Comment: Syntactically, is the clefted elements/phrase moved from the original position to the front?

Comment: That depends on whether your syntactic theory allows movement. It also depends on what your theory considers "the clefted element" to be, and the place your theory thinks "the original position" of the clefted element might be. Different theories say different things about these, which means that any answer is right, if you name the correct theory to go with it. In my theory, which is based on McCawley 1998, the focussed constituent is moved in both these rules, but in different directions. The focus is at the end in a _Wh_-cleft, but not an _It_-cleft.

Comment: I really sorry for sending reply late. Also, I really appriciate your kindful and concrete answer. I have to read McCawley 1998. Thank you very much.